# How to use user created variable in the same Test Case later in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am new to RF. I want to use user created variable later in the test case.
First I assigned value to a variable `${PL_VIN}` using keyword "**Get Text**". Now I want to input this value to a text box.In "`Output.xml`" file I am able to see that the value is assigned to `${PL_VIN}`.But when using it later i am getting error that "Variable not found". Do i need to add this user created variable to Locators file?

**Script**:

Assigned value as below:

```
${PL_VIN} = Get Text    ${VIN_Search Result_Title_WO_Acc_Info}
```

Using it later in the same test case as below:

```
Input Text  ${VIN_Test Box_Wrk_Dup_Title_WQ}    ${PL_VIN}
```

**Output in output.xml**

When Getting text:

```
msg level="INFO" timestamp="20150624 23:13:22.561">${PL_VIN} = SED1T0751ES624687</msg>
```

When using it later:

```
Variable '${PL_VIN}' not found. Did you mean: ${BPO_Link}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your line with varaible assignment misses a tabulator and output.xml just prints the line of source code.

Try

```
${PL_VIN} =    Get Text    ${VIN_Search Result_Title_WO_Acc_Info}
Log To Console    ${PL_VIN}    # just for debugging
```

if that does not work, the problem is the implementation of `Get Text`. It is not a built-in keyword but probably from selenium2library. If so, make sure that SED1T0751ES624687 (the value ${VIN_Search Result_Title_WO_Acc_Info} apparently resolves to) is a valid locator and check the whole output of output.xml for other error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your response Würgspaß.. but i have given the spaces properly... If you see the output, the text "SED1T0751ES624687" is getting assigned properly to ${PL_VIN}... but later i am not able to use...

Comment: @Devi: the code in your question does in fact have incorrect number of spaces. Make sure your question shows the _actual_ code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley:  In my text file the spaces are correct. But when copy and paste it here in website, it is becoming improper.

Comment: @Devi: all we have to go on is what is posted. It's your job to make sure the posted code accurately reflects your problem. A simple test is to copy and paste the code from your question into a new file and try to run it again yourself.

Comment: @Devi: I think you should edit your question and post more contents of your log files. Either output.xml or log.html. The line you've posted from `output.xml` is probably not the actual problem but some follow-up error.